# Run Compass/SASS with a different version

Tags: sass, compass-sass, susy-compass, blueprint

I am trying to find a nice solution working on two different compass projects. One is based off Compass using Blueprint (older version), and the other is based on susy grid (newer version).

Currently, I have to reinstall the right version for the `watch` process.

Is it possible to run `compile` with a specified version? It would be great if it is also possible to run a `watch` process with a specified version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running it as

```
compass _0.10.5_ compile
```

will do what you want. (Where you put in the desired version in place of 0.10.5, obviously.)

Answer (score 4):

The tool you're looking for is probally [rvm](https://rvm.io/) which allows you to have different versions of ruby/gems installed and easily switch between them.

Comment: ...and then there is [pik](http://github.com/vertiginous/pik/) for all the happy windows users out there.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there's a simpler way.
If you can use something like Codekit or Livereload, those tools allow you to used embedded sass libraries or define your own.

That you could use the builtin libraries for one project and your custom ones for other projects.

RVM suggested above also works i believe but never tried myself.