# Why does "compass watch" say it cannot load sass/script/node (LoadError)?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, compass-sass

I'm having a problem with my compass watch command - it worked fine up until a few days ago. I have made no changes to my config files.

I reinstalled Compass, used rvm to update Ruby. I checked my custom_require.rb file but I really don't know what to look for. It seems to be trying to load the file "sass/script/node" somewhere and from `http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Node.html` I gather the filepath - but I have nothing there.

```
/Users/sampurcell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass/script/node (LoadError)
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `each'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `each'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:8:in `fallback_load_path'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:19:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/compass:19:in `load'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/compass:19:in `<main>'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
  from /Users/sampurcell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Fixed it! I needed to reinstall sass - I originally tried running
`gem install sass`
but I first needed to run 
`gem uninstall sass`. Simple error, and while I'm not sure of the cause, it seems to be dependency related.

Comment: Am having similar issues with 3.3.0.alpha builds. The stable standard sass version seems to resolve the issue..

Comment: Free free to format your fix as an answer and mark it answered - solutions found by the one who asked the question are just as useful to posterity and the public.

Comment: @SamPurcell like you write in your comment, by reinstalling SASS i solved the same issue. Thanks. I think you should write an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Uninstall sass and reinstall it with the following:

```
gem uninstall sass
gem install sass
```

There was an issue with my installation of sass and doing this fixed the issue.

Comment: i adore how something so simple can solve such problems...i've also got to give Google and SO props for this being the second option in the query results

Comment: This worked for me on OS X. I actually had 2 sass versions on my computer, and perhaps that's why it wasn't working for me. When I uninstalled, I uninstalled both versions, then just did 'gem install sass', then compass worked.

Comment: This is amazing in a strictly negative way. (the shape of the solution, not your work, Mike)

Comment: This is silly - shouldn't sass be included with compass?

Comment: I had two versions installed, which I both removed. Installing again worked!

Comment: Re-installing sass didn't work for me, re-installing compass did. Looks like compass installs its own sass gem.

Comment: I had to do **gem uninstall compass** and **gem install compass** , then it worked!

Comment: I also had to run `rm Gemfile.lock` and then rebundled

Comment: This did not work for me as it installed the latest sass, not the one I needed for Compass to work with. This command actually caused my original issues ;)

Comment: This is a copy of the self-answer given by the OP seven months earlier. Though the OP posted it as a comment — the very first comment to the question, in plain view — instead of an answer, the right thing to do, rather than repost the answer as one's own, would have been to post a community wiki answer and [this is what I have now done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26951515/119775).

Answer (score 24):

In my case, Sass version was not compatible with Compass.

FIX :

1. uninstall Sass AND Compass

   ```
   gem uninstall compass
   gem uninstall sass
   ```
2. install Compass **who will install a compatible Sass engine automaticaly**

   ```
   gem install compass
   ```

Comment: That's really helpful. Indeed just uninstalling sass, didn't help me.

Comment: I had tried this myself and it didn't work - I had to use gemfiles. Maybe I did't execute these in the right order? Using Gemfiles, you get to specify exactly what gets installed and helps avoid anything in the future upgrading away from the required versions.

Comment: Thank you very much. Uninstalling sass really didn't help.

Comment: Thx. I needed sudo though

Answer (score 13):

This combination is finally working for me to bring Compass and SASS Sourcemaps together:

### Gemfile

```
gem 'sass', '3.3.0.alpha.149'
gem 'compass', '0.12.2'
gem 'compass-sourcemaps', "~> 0.12.2.sourcemaps.57a186c"
```

### Compass config.rb

```
sass_options = {:sourcemap => true}
```

Comment: THANK YOU. That took forever. The combination of sass 3.3.0.alpha.149 and compass 0.12.2 did the trick.

Comment: Checkout RubyGems to find out the exact dependencies for your version of compass - https://rubygems.org/gems/compass. See my post further down for info on how to do version ranges in gemfiles.

Answer (score 10):

This specific version works well on both:

```
gem 'sass', '3.3.0.alpha.149'
gem 'compass', '0.12.2'
```

They might not be compatible with each other that's why you're getting those errors (considering you're using a bleeding edge version).

Comment: I was struggling with this, also, trying to get SASS Source Maps to work. https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1339 targets this.

Answer (score 4):

In case you are using Ubuntu it may be a problem with apt-get and rvm colliding.

Try removing rvm with `rvm implode` 
and  then run

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-compass
```

`compass watch` worked for me after that.

Answer (score 3):

A variation on the above answers: for me (using Bootstrap for Sass), it turned out to be

```
gem install bootstrap-sass
```

that was needed in order to fix this problem. For me, the LoadError problem with Compass started after I updated the version of Ruby I was using.

Comment: Fixed it for me! (didn't realize bootstrap-sass was a ruby thing) thought it was a npm package or something else that I had already installed.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is due to versioning conflicts with sass.

https://rubygems.org/gems/compass gem is currently at `v0.12.16` currently - add this to Gemfile

```
gem 'sass', '3.2.19'
gem 'compass', '0.12.6'
```

You may be required to uninstall all versions of both gems first.

Comment: This is exactly what led me onto the right path to solving this, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix it by doing this

```
gem uninstall sass
gem install sass -v 3.2.12
```

This is definitely due to a version dependency issue, you are better off fixing your grunt task to make it forward compatible with the newer versions of saas, compass and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and then I realised that I had two compass versions, so by doing:

`compass watch` or `compass compile`

The compiler didn't know which compass version it should use to compile. So, what you can do is explicitly indicate the compass version to work with:

`compass _1.0.3_ watch`

There's another interesting [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454895/run-compass-sass-with-a-different-version).

Answer (score 0):

The following combinations worked for me:

```
gem install compass --pre
gem install sass -v 3.3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to setup a gemfile with the correct versions (this error is caused by mismatched SASS and Compass versions, for me). I used thew following with `bundle install` to fix the problem:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'bootstrap-sass', "~> 3.2.0"
gem 'sass', [ "< 3.5" , ">= 3.3.13" ]
gem 'compass', "~> 1.0.1"
gem 'compass-core', "~> 1.0.1"
gem 'compass-import-once', "~> 1.0.5"
gem 'chunky_png', "~> 1.2"
gem 'rb-fsevent', ">= 0.9.3"
gem 'rb-inotify', ">= 0.9"
```