# Errors running Grunt and Sass

Tags: gruntjs, compass, twitter-bootstrap-4

I've been trying to get Sass up and running with Bootstrap. I've followed [the tutorial](https://designmodo.com/bootstrap-4-npm-grunt-sass/), going so far as to install exact versions of the dependencies listed rather than the default/latest versions.  I've done this from scratch at least three times. I've uninstalled and reinstalled different versions of Sass and Compass (mainly according to [Sass --compass --watch Error: Cannot load compass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038402/sass-compass-watch-error-cannot-load-compass)), as well as older versions of Ruby (I just installed 2.3.3, down from the latest release).

But whenever I get to running the `grunt sass` command, something goes wrong.  I've gotten errors about not being able to load Compass.  If I search and rectify that, I'll go through an error or two more (not on hand sorry, I've closed everything out), but keep ending up on:

```
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.1.0.alpha.3/lib/compass/core/caniuse.rb:72: warning: circular argument reference - browsers
NoMethodError: ┬á
  Use --trace for backtrace.
Warning: Exited with error code 1 Use --force to continue.
```

I've looked up this error, and I've tried doing the bundle update [listed here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/7244576-warning-circular-argument-reference-browsers-with-mri-2-2-0), but end up right back where I started with the same problems (since now there are updated versions of dependencies that apparently don't play well together, and compass things don't work again).

I know how to use Sass, I just can't practice since I can't get it running.  I'm newer to coding, and I don't know Ruby at all, so I'm stuck now that my search-fu has failed me.  My machine is running Windows 10. I am specifically looking to set up Sass to run with Bootstrap 4 (yes, I know it's in alpha, it's what I'm required to use for work) and there doesn't seem to be any good documentation out there about how to actually get it running properly.

Comment: I have the same error with a smaller setup. I don't use grunt. I called `gem update --system && gem update` on the command line to update my setup. I got `Sass 3.5.1 (Bleeding Edge)` Now every call to `sass` on the command line fails with the message `ERROR: Cannot load compass.` Calls to `gem install compass` or `gem install compass -pre` did not help. I eventually uninstalled `sass` in the most current version; `gem uninstall sass` lists the versions available to uninstall. Everything works again.

Comment: `gem install sass --version 3.4.25` should help after uninstalling latest `sass`

Comment: I did all of these things -- still wind up with one error or another, that requires a fix I've tried, and generally ends up with me an hour later with the same error I've started with.  For the time being I gave up and decided that Compass was forged by the hand of Satan himself, and found ways to do Sass without it.

Comment: I still get this error with `sass-3.5.6` and `compass-core-1.1.0.alpha.3`