# Compass installation under rbenv

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass, rbenv, codekit

I thought I had Compass installed OK using rbenv on my Mac, but I got an error when trying to switch Codekit to use it instead of its internal compiler.

Running `compass -v` in the terminal gives me:

```
/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass/script/node (LoadError)
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `each'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `each'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:8:in `fallback_load_path'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:19:in `<top (required)>'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/bin/compass:23:in `load'
from /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
```

So, it would seem there's a problem there, although running `gem install compass` tells me that compass-0.12.2 was successfully installed.

How do I go about working out what the problem is and fixing it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877028/compass-watch-cannot-load-such-file-sass-script-node-loaderror

Comment: The error message says that SASS can't be located. What does `gem list sass` show?

Comment: Yep, that's the same issue as mine and it's fixed now, thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this version,

http://rubygems.org/gems/sass/versions/3.3.0.alpha.149

```
gem install sass -v 3.3.0.alpha.149 --pre
```

Bear in mind that the command above installs the gem, it doesn't activate the version!

You can run the following:

```
gem uninstall sass
```

You'll be prompted with a list of installed versions; merely uninstall the ones that are 3.3.0.alpha.X where X is higher then 149.

You can test it works via:

```
sass --version
compass --version
```

You should see normal pages (instead of the errors in your question).

ps.

You may need this too:

```
gem install compass-sourcemaps -v 0.12.2.sourcemaps.57a186c --pre
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was an incompatibility between compass and sass. It was "sass-3.3.0.rc.2" installed automatically via compass dependencies.

So I had to remove sass version `gem uninstall sass` and install another version `gem install sass -v 3.2.12`

After that, the errors disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with some imports in one script within compass. An easy fix, but for now you can add this to your Gemfile (works for me right now):

```
gem "compass", github: 'ovaskevich/compass'
```