# compass watch error - Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, sass

I've been running sass and compass for a few months now and yesterday I was having some problems with ruby and an unrelated project. So in the end I re-installed ruby and sass.

Since then I can no longer run compass watch without getting the error below.

```
##########:######### #########$ compass watch
/Users/#############/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass/script/node (LoadError)
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:122:in `require'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `each'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `each'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:8:in `fallback_load_path'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/compass:23:in `load'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/#############/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

None of the other compass commands seem to be working either, so I reinstalled compass and I still get the same error.

Here are the versions of ruby and sass I am running. compass -v doesn't work.

ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
Sass 3.3.0.alpha.253 (Bleeding Edge)

Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix this please?

Comment: Can you check your paths with $PATH? Maybe you simply have to add the absolute path to compass.

Comment: @Rito
-bash: /Users/########/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/########/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/Users/########/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/########/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin: No such file or directory

Ive never had to mess about like this before.

Comment: Duplicate Question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877028/why-does-compass-watch-say-it-cannot-load-sass-script-node-loaderror

Answer (score 13):

### It looks like you might have a version of SASS that doesn't work with this version of Compass

*I found the answer here: https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1514*

The following worked for me:

#### Look at the version of SASS you have installed (you said Sass 3.3.0.alpha.253)

```
sass --version
```

#### Uninstall sass:

```
sudo gem uninstall sass
```

#### Reinstall sass - you should get the latest working version:

```
sudo gem install sass
```

#### Reinstall Compass (I did this and it kept my working version of SASS):

```
sudo gem install compass
```

Comment: Perfect. Went from sass-3.3.0.rc.2 to  sass-3.2.14 and reinstalled Compass. Would never've guessed it. Thanks.