# I am trying to create sample app using yeoman and backbone but display some error can anyone help me?

Tags: ruby, node.js, backbone.js, gruntjs, yeoman

i have alerady install following thing in pcs

- Node
- Npm
- yeoman
- backbone-generator
- ruby with saas and compass

> But still display following error when run grunt command in command
>   prompt.
>
> C:\Users\Nirav\Desktop\Backbone\NodeWebkit\TestYeoman>grunt build
>   Running "clean:dist" (clean) task Cleaning .tmp...OK
>
> Running "coffee:dist" (coffee) task
>
> Running "coffee:test" (coffee) task
>
> Running "createDefaultTemplate" task
>
> Running "jst:compile" (jst) task
>
> > > Destination not written because compiled files were empty.
>
> Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- sass/script/node (LoadError)
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in`
>   rescue in require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in
>   `require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1:in`'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2:in
>   `block in <top (required)>'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in`
>   each'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in`
>   '
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5:in
>   `block in <top (required)>'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in`
>   each'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:20:in`
>   block in '
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:8:in
>   `fallback_load_path'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:19:in`
>   '
>           from C:/Ruby193/bin/compass:23:in `load'
>           from C:/Ruby193/bin/compass:23:in`' Warning: ↑ Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.
>
> Execution Time (2014-01-09 18:06:03 UTC) loading tasks   2.8s 
>   ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
>   83% compass:dist   556ms  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 16% Total 3.4s
>
> C:\Users\Nirav\Desktop\Backbone\NodeWebkit\TestYeoman>

Can any one help me to solve following error? this is my first experiment for node yeoman and backbone please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and got it running.
There is a version conflict with compass and sass both of which are needed by the framework you installed via the yo command.

gem uninstall compass sass

gem install sass compass

Idea stolen from here.
[Why does "compass watch" say it cannot load sass/script/node (LoadError)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877028/why-does-compass-watch-say-it-cannot-load-sass-script-node-loaderror)