# Spree_fancy sass source maps issue rails

Tags: sass, spree

I am trying to setup sass source maps so I can edit the scss in Chrom Dev tools  with the aim of editing spree's spree_fancy theme sass.

I can get source maps working  working on a plain site , but when I try to set up the same method using the spree fancy extension I get the following error when I start the rails server

```
mspree@ubuntu-dev-desktop:~/fancy$ rails s 
/home/mspree/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass/script/node (LoadError)
    from /home/mspree/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
```

Gemfile is

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.1'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'sass-rails', github: "rails/sass-rails"
gem 'sass', git: 'https://github.com/nex3/sass.git'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development do
   gem 'coffee-rails-source-maps'
   gem 'sass-rails-source-maps'
end

gem 'spree', '2.1.4'
gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch => '2-1-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git', :branch => '2-1-stable'
gem 'spree_fancy', :github => 'spree/spree_fancy', :branch => '2-1-stable
```

I soon as I comment out the spree_fancy gem the rails server starts ok, but as expected the site wont load as it cannot find the spree_fancy stuff I've commented out.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You may find this solution helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877028/why-does-compass-watch-say-it-cannot-load-sass-script-node-loaderror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the version of the sass gem. I had the edge version. I went back one dot version and it worked. 3.0.2.rc2 I believe.