# Carrierwave wrong number of arguments on showing the thumbnail

Tags: rubygems, sass, sinatra

I'm trying to implement `sassy-buttons` with Sinatra but I'm having an error.

error

```
Boot Error

Something went wrong while loading config.ru
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sass/script/node

/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1:in `require'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2:in `require'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `each'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `require'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5:in `require'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `each'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/sassy-buttons-0.2.6/lib/sassy-buttons.rb:1:in `require'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/sassy-buttons-0.2.6/lib/sassy-buttons.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user1/Documents/programming/rails_book/tuto/Sinatra/blog_sinatra/app.rb:5:in `require'
/home/user1/Documents/programming/rails_book/tuto/Sinatra/blog_sinatra/app.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
config.ru:2:in `require'
config.ru:2:in `block in inner_app'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `inner_app'
```

my config.ru

```
# config.ru
require "./app"
run Sinatra::Application
```

my app.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require "sinatra"
require "sass"
require "sinatra/activerecord"
require 'sassy-buttons'

set :database, "sqlite3:///blog.db"

get '/styles.css' do
    scss :styles
end

configure do
  set :show_exceptions, false
end
```

In  my Gemfile I did include `gem "sass" and the gem "sassy-buttons"`

on my stylesheet

```
$mainColor:#002b36;
$secColor:#eee;

@import "sassy-buttons"

body{
background: $secColor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem may relate to sass version, it seems similar problem has already described there [Why does "compass watch" say it cannot load sass/script/node (LoadError)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877028/why-does-compass-watch-say-it-cannot-load-sass-script-node-loaderror) , so it may help to specify sass version in your Gemfile or just uninstall and install it again